# Success compilation of phantomjs on Raspberry 2 but not executing (libjpeg.so.8)

Tags: compilation, phantomjs, raspbian, libjpeg, raspberry-pi2

In my raspberry 2 with updated version of OSMC I would like to use PhantomJS with selenium in python and tried to compile it.

Following this link: 
[How to compile phantomjs on the raspberry pi 2](http://raspberrypimaker.com/how-to-compile-phantomjs-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/)

And this link: [Adding swap for the raspberry pi](http://raspberrypimaker.com/adding-swap-to-the-raspberrypi/)

Created swap file of 16Gb in USB disk and compiled correctly phantomjs.

When i try to execute it:

```
phantomjs --version
```

I receive following error:

```
phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched here and on google about installing this file but I can't find information. Tried to install binary phantomjs for raspberry pi2 from github and obtained same error, this is the reason to try to compile it, but receive same error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

when trying to execute compiled binary the problem was that following command:

```
$ cd /home/TOSHIBA/fuente/phantomjs/bin
$ phantomjs
```

Was executing previuous binary version (2.0.0) installed on my /usr/bin downloaded from github of another user.

Now the problem is solved with compiled binary on my Raspberry2:

```
$ cd /home/TOSHIBA/fuente/phantomjs/bin
$ ./phantomjs --version
    2.0.1-development
$ ldd phantomjs
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicudata.so.52 (0x758d0000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x75887000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x75762000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x7572a000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so.6 (0x756b5000)
    libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62 (0x7566c000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng12.so.0 (0x75642000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0x75620000)
    libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicui18n.so.52 (0x754c8000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicuuc.so.52 (0x753bc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x753a9000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x75392000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x7536f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x752b8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x75244000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7521b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x7512c000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f56000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libexpat.so.1 (0x75104000)
```

If anyone is interested, I have uploaded compressed version of binary to my dropbox account, you can download it here:

[PhantomJS 2.0.1-development binary for Raspberry-Pi2](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0r9cmaasg4vzpcb/AAA4VQBFR_NuIXCeYabFvIGFa?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you Jorge, to get your PhantomJS-Binary running on Raspbian which still depends on wheezy I had to install the libicu*52 and libjpeg62 from Jessie via libjpeg-dev and icu-devtools. Working great while failing before to get it compiled. Thanks.